# Pytorch differentiable conditional (index-based) sum

Tags: python, pytorch

I have an `idx` array like `[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1]` and another 2d array `data` like the following:

```
[[0,  1,  2],
 [3,  4,  5],
 [6,  7,  8],
 [9,  10, 11],
 [12, 13, 14],
 [15, 16, 17]]
```

I want my output to be `4x3` in which 4 is the max of `idx` and 3 is the feature size (`data.shape[1]`) and in the output each element is the sum of features with corresponding index in the `idx`. Then output in this example would be:

```
[[6,  8,  10],
 [18, 20, 22],
 [9,  10, 11],
 [12, 13, 14]]
```

I can do it with iterating over `range(3)` and creating a mask on data and summing up them but it's not differentiable (I suppose). Is there any function(s) in Pytorch for this purpose? something like `scatter()`.

Update: It seems I am looking for something named *scatter sum* which is implemented in [this](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter) repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`index_add_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_add_):

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.],
        [ 9., 10., 11.],
        [12., 13., 14.],
        [15., 16., 17.]], dtype=torch.float)
idx = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1], dtype=torch.long)  # note the dtype here, must be "long"
# init the sums to zero
y = torch.zeros((idx.max()+1, x.shape[1]), dtype=x.dtype)

# do the magic
y.index_add_(0, idx, x)
```

Gives the desired output

> ```
> tensor([[ 6.,  8., 10.],
>         [18., 20., 22.],
>         [ 9., 10., 11.],
>         [12., 13., 14.]])
> ```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Then, no need to third party packages :-D